# Saving secure files in PHP include folder

Tags: php, apache, security, database-connection

On the Apache Server it is possible to define a directory for PHP includes. The path to the include folder is out of root, and does not conflict with the server script. The reason why I think it is nice to store the secure files like `config.php` and `db-access.php` in the PHP global include folder, is that I don't have to define the path for each and every single page in my web application. I can simply do as following:

```
<?
require_once('config.php');
require_once('db-access.php');
?>
```

But then I have a question cause, besides that the include folder is outside of root, is it still save enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be save enough, it you wouldn't place it under your htdocs folder ( folder, which is accessible via you web server ). So, you can put it in any other places.

Answer (score 0):

Way to include file from root directroy

```
<?php 
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= '/folder/config.php';
require_once($path);
?>
```

OR Use if they are in your `public_html` or `www` folder

```
 Order allow,deny
deny from all
```

Comment: The files are way back out of the root, so I don't think there is a need for .htaccess.. :)

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted your files are out of your `www` or `public_html` they are already secure from outside world.? Now what you really want

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted if you want path to include them use this `<?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= '/folder/config.php';
require_once($path);
?>`

Comment: I guess i was just paranoid. Since it was so easy and basic, so I just wanted to know what the problems would be about it. But I guess that it actually is okay to do so. I just had rewritten everything in my application because everybody told me about security and how o do so.. I just wanted to be sure wether or not this was secure enough.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted In short, yes they are secure from outsiders

Answer (score 0):

use .htacces

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```